# Magento 1.9.2.2 Product Editor error

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, error

I got a following error. When I go to `Product editor` i cant see the `text field`. How can I fix it.

http://prntscr.com/n0ca4d

http://prntscr.com/n0cafh

Comment: you can check console error